# How do I rerun a script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a script that will check if a record exist and if it does then it will exit.  Now I am trying to find out how to re-run the script if record exist:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Please enter hostname?
read hostname
echo
grep -q $hostname /home/user/ps/database
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo Record exist
  echo
fi
```

Now I want to re-run the script if record exist.  Please help

Comment: Don't try to re-run the script. Use a loop instead

Comment: Technically I suppose you could re-run the script with something like `exec "$0" $@`, but you don't really want to do that here – a `while` loop is a better solution.

Comment: @Arkku, that would need to be `"$@"` with the quotes to avoid splitting  `./myscript "One Argument"` into `./myscript "One" "Argument"`.

Answer (score 2):

You just need a simple loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :; do
  echo Please enter hostname?
  read hostname
  echo

  if grep -q $hostname /home/user/ps/database
  then
    echo Record exist
    echo
  else
    break
  fi
done
```